# How can I define an interface or type in TypeScript for my constant?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I am trying to define an interface or type for my dataset but I get some errors. Below the wrong interfaces and code I am using:

```
interface IVehicle {
    [key: number]: { model: string, year: number };
}
interface IVehicles {
    [type: string]: Array<IVehicle>
}

const DATASET: IVehicles = {
    CAR: [
        ["BMW", {
            model: "520d",
            year: 2015,
        }],
        ["Audi", {
            model: "A4",
            year: 2011,
        }]
    ],
    MOTORCYCLE: [
        ["YAMAHA", {
            model: "R6",
            year: 2020,
        }],
        ["DUCATI", {
            model: "Monster",
            year: 2018,
        }]
    ]
}

console.log(DATASET);
```

Typescript showed me the error:

> ```
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ model: string; year: number; }'.
> ```

**TypeScript Playground with the code:** [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDUIAtgIDYoDeAsAFDIXIDaA1hAJ4BcyIArgLYBG0Aus4cnYB7ACYQ8zAM5gooAOYAaZPQhwozNl2jIAvgG4yOsqEixEKDNlwFJyEuUpUw9AA4QpM+X2QBBKFDh6AB5LHHwIAD5DMjIEIRBpZAARHwAVHwBlAFFU5lDrCFsAXjsySmQAYR8AJWYqMvLHACIAIQBZAHUmpXtGvsFRcWYmgFYAJgAGEW6G-soVNWZJgEYRhVnGnR51hz6qJp9WEWBu0t25gbEJZAOAFhnzuYX1ZBXlnbmtje2NtoB5VJ-aoVACaFQAMlk6htyvsQT42j4ABI+U69C4UYRXYbVABsDwxFGeSwmkw+-S25L2TSSAFUqqlUGiYf0sUMbm14tJoATCcTXhNlgAOKmbHjfaKkWJcoQEAB0eCEcgAFCl0tlUgBKAykIA)

Comment: I think you want a _tuple type_, `{ [key: number]: { ... } }` makes no sense for an array where you expect only two values, one of which you expect **not** be an object of that shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
type IVehicle = [string, { model: string, year: number }];

interface IVehicles {
    [type: string]: Array<IVehicle>
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgahAFgSwMYBtoF4oG0DOwATsgHYDmANFAN5QC2A9gCYToBcUhJF1IEAQyKdSAV3oAjCESgBfALoBuALAAoNWWDSAZgNTR4SNJny01UC3lCRO3MuXmcAgkSICQAHkMoMEAHxqsmpqqIykhFAAIk4AKk4AygCiMZzexhCmODTmlgDCTgBKnLg5lpa4AEQAQgCyAOoV1NmqZa2WTKwcUBUArABMAAzMjaVtlvxCnIMAjD2Uo2UK8y1jlU6izMiNZitj7SxsnBVOACwju3tQE8JQM9PLewqj8g%20WNQDyMe8FuQCauQAZRLFBblCq-Jw1JwACSc22al32nSOBQAbOdERZrlMBoNXm0lqCLJVIgBVfIxGDwomtDqHbo1MKEaQYzHY24DaYADnxrSeF3kgWCqlC4UYmAAdOhGOQABTROJJGIAShUqiAA)